# MongoDB getting old data, is it due to cache or incorrect use of async/await?

Tags: database, mongodb, express, caching

I've created an API using MongoDB and ExpressJS. I'm doing some manipulations on an object in a collection, and then immediately afterwards getting it with a GET call.

```js
post('/cars/1/wheels', {}...)
.delete('/cars/1/doors/1')
.delete('/cars/1/doors/2')
.get('/cars/1')
```

I created the REST-Api using async functions, and added `await` before all manipulating `MongoDB` calls.

However, when the car object is fetched from the car collection above, it sometimes is not the current object with the manipulations, (It is outdated and will contain the two doors for example). It's rather unpredictable. When I check in the database all the manipulations have gone trough.

Could it be that MongoDB is returning a cached version of the object in the collection? Is it possible to tell MongoDB to make a manipulation and force it to update the cache?

## Edit:

I'm having a hard time isolating the problem and, I can't even find a deterministic way to reproduce the problem, so I'm unable to create a minimum runnable example. The issue occurs, and when I do exactly the same thing again it doesn't occur.

The text above was just an illustrative example, this is what I'm actually doing. I'm doing three deletes in rapid succession and then getting the editor like this:

```js
delete(/api/editors/editorId/editor-files/file1.png)
.then(data => 
   delete(/api/editors/editorId/editor-files/file2.png)
)
.then(data => 
   delete(/api/editors/editorId/editor-files/file3.png)
)
.then(data => 
   get(/api/editors/editorId)
)
```

This is part of the server code

```js
.delete('/api/editors/:editorId/editor-files/:name', async function (req, res, next) {

    const editor = await dbo.collection("editors").findOne({
        _id: ObjectId(req.params.editorId)
    })
    if(!req.user || req.user._id.toString() !==  editor.authorId) return res.send({needLogin:true})

    const fileInfo = editor.editedArticle.uploadedFiles.find( file => file.name === req.params.name )

    // Delete binary
    await dbo.collection('files').deleteOne({
        _id: ObjectId(fileInfo.mediaId)
    })

    // Delete file info
    await dbo.collection("editors").updateOne(
        {_id: ObjectId(req.params.editorId)},
        { 
            $pull: { 'editedArticle.uploadedFiles': { name:req.params.name } },
        },
    )

    await updateArticleCardThumbnail(req.params.editorId, dbo)

    res.send({})
})

async function updateArticleCardThumbnail(editorId, dbo) {
    const editor = await dbo.collection("editors").findOne({
        _id: ObjectId(editorId)
    })
    const uploadedFiles = editor.editedArticle.uploadedFiles
    let base64 = await getArticleCardThumbnailBase64FromUploadedFiles(uploadedFiles, dbo)
    await dbo.collection('editors').updateOne(
        {_id: ObjectId(editorId),},
        {$set: { 
            'editedArticle.cardThumbnailBase64' : base64
        }}
    )
}

async function getArticleCardThumbnailBase64FromUploadedFiles(uploadedFiles, dbo) {
    let images = uploadedFiles.filter( f => /png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|bmp/ig.test(f.mimetype))
    let imageNameBackground = images.find( f => /^thumbnail\..*$/.test(f.name))
    let backgroundImage = imageNameBackground || images[0]
    let base64
    if(backgroundImage) {
        const imageWithBinary = await dbo.collection("files").findOne({ _id: ObjectId(backgroundImage.mediaId) })
        const buffer = await sharp(imageWithBinary.data.buffer).resize(
            500, 500, {
                fit: 'inside',
            }
        ).toBuffer()
        base64 = `data:${backgroundImage.mimetype};base64,${buffer.toString('base64')}`
    }
    return base64
}
```

And in the GET endpoint i'm just getting the editor with: `db.collection("editors").find(filter).toArray()`

I've logged the requests, so I know that the deletes returns before get. But the `editor.editedArticle.uploadedFiles` will contain some of old uploaded file models. If I wait for a couple of seconds or refresh the page, everything is consistent.

Is it perhaps due to improper use of `async/await` in the delete endpoint above? Have I misunderstood async/await code somewhere?

Edit 2: Removed PseudoCode, added actual api-calls, changed title and some text.

Comment: *"Could it be that MongoDB is returning a cached version of the object in the collection?"* - Probably not, and it's more than likely an issue with the way you have implemented the code. Possibly you are using `findOneAndUpdate()` or similar? If so there is a common pitfall there for many new users. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete and Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the problem

Comment: Hi @NeilLunn, I'm having problem creating a mwe. The issue only happens in some cases with only a certain types of data and when I use the Chrome simulator set to *fast 3G*. What is that common pitfall? I've included some of the async server code, sorry if it's to messy...

Comment: To be completely clear *"Could it be that MongoDB is returning a cached version.."* is a very clear statement which is very easy to test. All it needs is a very small sample of code, which is *backend only* and has nothing to do with Chome simulator or any such case. Whilst you might have a an actual implementation with many moving parts, that in itself is far too broad a question. Questions here *testing* each part individually are welcome if you need that assistance. And that is exactly the point of the site help link you were given.

Comment: As to the code you have included so far, the main thing missing here is the actual case showing things not occuring as you might expect. I also note the term *psuedocode* which would suggest this is not actually how you are implementing your API calls. The general conclusion would be that since nothing in the API appears to *tie* the delete action completion to the eventual request, that the real problem here is your code implementing those calls does not correctly **await** the completion of those deletes before requesting a new copy of the object.

Comment: @NeilLunn Sorry about the term psuedocode, I just meant that it's not runnable as it is. What was the "If so there is a common pitfall there for many new users..." you where talking about on the first comment? Yes, that is also what I thought could be a possible error, **incorrect usage of async await*.